# loading rss feed into php

Tags: php, rss

What's the best way to load an RSS feed into a PHP feed?

I also want to handle the `media:content` problems to display a image.
At this moment I have the following code but I don't know if this is the best.

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.hln.be/rss.xml');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'media' => $node->getElementsByTagName('media:content url')->item(0)->nodeValue,

            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 20;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        $image = $feed[$x]['media'];

        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '"/>';

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this:

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.hln.be/rss.xml');

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $title       = (string) $item->title;
  $description = (string) $item->description;

  print '<div>';

  printf(
    '<h2>%s</h2><p>%s</p>', 
    $title, 
    $description
  );

  if ($media = $item->children('media', TRUE)) {
    if ($media->content->thumbnail) {
      $attributes = $media->content->thumbnail->attributes();
      $imgsrc     = (string)$attributes['url'];

      printf('<div><img src="%s" alt="" /></div>', $imgsrc);
    }
  }

  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Ok thankyou, can you please ad an example to print some text with this, because in my example i used the dom elements.

Comment: @ioseb: A little hint: printf with the `%s` will make PHP cast the simplexml elements to string, so you do not need the `(string)` casts if you use printf ;)

Comment: @hakre i did this for reason, this is a very brief example. to be safe SimpleXMLElements must be casted to appropriate types for proper reuse. in this particular case i agree with you though.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this code to make the title a link to the actual post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.hln.be/rss.xml');

print_r($feed);

?>
```

This gives you object/array structure which you can use directly instead of communicating with additional layer(i.e. DOM) on top of the data.

Comment: When i use that code, the only thing i get is text. but i'm still not able to get to the images

Comment: You need to fetch images separately. Images(and obviously other media information) are not embedded inside RSS document. RSS spec provides only links to external resources which need to be fetched like browser does in HTML's case.

Comment: I understand, they provide a link like this <media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://static2.demorgen.be/static/photo/2012/13/10/7/20120516122633/media_s_4832872.jpg">
<media:thumbnail url="http://static2.demorgen.be/static/photo/2012/13/10/7/20120516122633/media_s_4832872.jpg" />
</media:content> but how do i get trough this. I understand the principes of img src = variable

Comment: see my another answer with code example, sorry initially i didn't understand your question.

Comment: Ok thank you, But now i have the following question. Is it possible to load every article in a separate div class? Its a sort of read later app. When you click on a button near the article, the article will be copied to another place. Anybody knows where i can start?