# Unable to read RSS feed from Wired using PHP

Tags: php, rss

I am facing a strange problem of reading RSS feed from Wired using PHP. I want display the feed in my Website. I am using the below code to fetch the feed. Can anyone please let me know where exactly I am doing wrong.

```
try {
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('https://www.wired.com/category/reviews/feed/');
    if ($rss->validate()) {
        echo "This document is valid!\n";
    }else{
        echo "This document is not valid!\n";
    }
}catch (Exception $e) {
    return array('error'=>'Error raised in reading the feed','exception'=>$e);
}

$feeds =  array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feeds, $item);
}
```

After excecuting the above code I am getting the following error

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in https://www.wired.com/category/reviews/feed/, line: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_functions\index.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): no DTD found! in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_functions\index.php on line 5
This document is not valid!
```

I also checked for the validity of the Wired feed url in the "Feed validator (https://www.feedvalidator.org/) and its saying its a valid RSS feed...

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i believe this is xml try to load it by simplexml_load_file function

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617142/loading-rss-feed-into-php

Comment: If you want to handle RSS, this one is a nice project: https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/

Comment: This method 'simplexml_load_file' is not working for me. Its throwing,  

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://www.wired.com/category/reviews/feed/:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_functions\index.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code in my way using `curl` and `simplexml`:

```
$handle = curl_init('https://www.wired.com/category/reviews/feed/');

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

curl_close($handle);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
// print_r($data);
$feeds =  array();
if(isset($data['channel']['item'])) {
    foreach($data['channel']['item'] as $item) {
        $feeds[] =  array(
            'title' =>  $item['title'],
            'desc'  =>  $item['description'],
            'link'  =>  $item['link'],
        );
    }
}
print_r($feeds);
```

Comment: Wow..the above code is working for me but where exactly I was failing in my code?

Comment: it also works on `DOMDocument` flavor, it just likes to be used thru `curl`. the `file_get_contents` just messes up the return value

Comment: @Ghost yes, for `https` `file_get_contents` sending gzip encrypted content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gaurav.. and My version with Domdocument

```
define('RSS_FEED_URL', 'https://www.wired.com/category/reviews/feed/');
try {
    // fetch the rss feeds from wired!
    $handle = curl_init(RSS_FEED_URL);

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->loadXML($response);
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failed to fetch RSS Feed properly for Blogs!!";
    return array();
}

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $feeds[] = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        // 'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
}
```