# display data from Rss file

Tags: php, rss

i am trying to display data from Rss file
here my code and when i upload it to server i got blank page.

any solution's please

```
  <?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('test.rss');

echo '<h4>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h4>';

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   echo '<h4><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h4>";
   echo "<p>" . $item->title . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
} 
?>
```

i got this error in error_log

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): Failed to enable crypto in
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(test.rss): failed to open stream: operation failed in
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Comment: This SO thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617142/loading-rss-feed-into-php

Comment: Hi thank you ,i will check the link thx

Comment: @SJacks same error i got .